# How to specify the question to the textview in android studio java?

Tags: java, android

I have a random question and I have a problem detecting which question should be in the TextView of course. So I have to specify that if this question, the multiple choices will be shown. This is my code:

This is my question:

```java
Random r = new Random();

String [] quest = {"Which alphabet will be 14th to the left of 8th alphabet from the right in the following series of letters?" +
        "A O B P C Q D R E S F T G U H V I W J X K Y L Z M N.", "Hritik is taller than Salman who is shorter than Sanjay. Akshay is taller than " +
        "Shahrukh but shorter than Salman. Sanjay is shorter than Hritik. Who is the tallest?" , "Lali and Anju are a married couple. Tunu and Munu " +
        "are brothers. Tunu is the brother of Lali. How is Munu related to Anju?", "How many sets of two letters have as many letters " +
        "between them as in the English alphabetical order in the word ‘WRISTWATCH’."};

boolean [] usedIndices = new boolean[quest.length];
```

This are my main code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);

    Button question = findViewById(R.id.btnQuestion);
    final Button answer = findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer);
    final TextView ask = findViewById(R.id.txtAsk);

    question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            QuestionCount QC = new QuestionCount();
            int indextoBeUsed;
            do {
                indextoBeUsed = r.nextInt(quest.length);
            }
            while (usedIndices[indextoBeUsed]);
            usedIndices[indextoBeUsed] = true;
            ask.setText(quest[indextoBeUsed]);
            count += 1;

            if (ask.setText("Which alphabet will be 14th to the left of 8th alphabet from the right in the following series of letters?")) { // This part I got an error. For example, if this question appeared in the textview, the right multiple choices will be shown in the buttons.

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, you have to check the question using get text and not set text. For eg., tv.getText() == "yourQuestion" will give you your solution

Comment: Thank you I get it.